# Align text styled with line-height

Tags: css

Is there a way to align text that has the `line-height` property ?
`border-box` doesn't seem to help, since css is counting the lineheight as part of the actual font. I tried using negative offsets, but those don't seem to do much.

I am currently using `flexbox` for all of the layout.

### The layout

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                           |
| +-----------------------------------+                                                                     |
| |                                   |                                                                     |
| |  Title                            |                                                                     |
| |                                   |                                                                     |
| +-----------------------------------+                                                                     |
|                                                                                                           |
| +-------------------------------------------------+  +-----------------------------------------------+    |
| |                                                 |  |                                               |    |
| | Image                                           |  | Text                                          |    |
| |                                                 |  |                                               |    |
| |                                                 |  |                                               |    |
| |                                                 |  |                                               |    |
| |                                                 |  |                                               |    |
| |                                                 |  |                                               |    |
| |                                                 |  |                                               |    |
| |                                                 |  +-----------------------------------------------+    |
| |                                                 |                                                       |
| |                                                 |                                                       |
| |                                                 |  +------------+                                       |
| |                                                 |  |   button   |                                       |
| +-------------------------------------------------+  +------------+                                       |
|                                                                                                           |
|                                                                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### The offset

[image: Text is not aligned]

### Css (EmotionJs for React)

```js
<div css={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    }}>
    <Img
        customCss={{
            backgroundPosition: ['center', 'bottom'],
            flexGrow: 1,
        }}
    />
    <div
        css={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'flex-start',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
        }}>
        <div
            css={{
                lineHeight: '1.5em',
            }}>
            {text}
        </div>
        <a>Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Solutions :

[Found a selector that can remove line-height from the first line](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp), but that messes with the spacing for the second line

Comment: Can you please add your html as well? That gives us a little more insight on the situation. Or maybe even a code snippet/jsfiddle, that would be great.

Comment: @ThomasTromp I did provide the html structure :D Its in the css "box"

Comment: Ah yes, I see, excuse me. I'm not familiar to React yet.

Comment: @ThomasTromp I wanted the text to align with the image container, but because of the `line-height` property it pushes it down. I was wondering whether there are good solutions to this problem, like disabling `line-height` for the first line of text (seems impossible), pushing up the text with a negative offset (seems also impossible) or wraping the image and the text-button and then offsetting the image (seems like a hack & not intuitive at all)

Comment: Can you provide me with a code-snippet or jsfiddle? That it more clear (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the line height for the first line using [::first-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line#:%7E:text=The%20%3A%3Afirst%2Dline%20CSS,font%20size%20of%20the%20text.) but it will also affect the distance between the first and second line, so that's not good.

The best you can do is add a negative top margin to the child element using em, so in case you have different text-sizes it should be still work.

```css
.c, .c > div {
  background: gainsboro;
  display: flex;
}
.c > div > div {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-top: -.35em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRC02.png">
    <div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tristique dui erat, in cursus nibh dapibus et. Nulla efficitur vestibulum vestibulum. Integer lacinia laoreet mattis. Sed mattis, magna in mollis sagittis, purus enim varius ligula, id eleifend felis massa at leo. Maecenas dapibus nunc nec ullamcorper euismod. Etiam odio elit, tempus ac diam eu, efficitur mollis lectus. Morbi efficitur mollis metus, malesuada varius diam pharetra a. Maecenas id turpis non est pulvinar suscipit. Nullam fringilla lectus in dui dapibus scelerisque.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I used a negative offset before, but for whatever reason forgot to add a unit ... . Why is the offset -.35 em though ?

Comment: It depends on the font. Your line-height is 1.5 (no need to specify unit in this property), the font itself is 1em, so 1.5 - 1 = .5, as half goes above and half below the text, it should be 2.5em, but the font itself may have some white space included, depending on the character, in this case -3.5em seemed like the best fit, but you will have to tune it a bit depending on your font. -2.5em should look pretty good in any case though